# What can I do to optimize my .NET Web sites and applications for 64-bit?

Tags: asp.net, performance, optimization, 64-bit

How can I take full advantage of 64-bit architecture in my .NET 2.0 Web Applications and Console/Forms Applications?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not too much you can optimize in your managed .NET code regarding 32bit vs. 64bit architectures. This is because most of the differences and optimizatinons are most likely already implemented by the underlying VM. As mentioned in [Programming for the 64 bit platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280327/programming-for-the-64-bit-platform), the 64bit VM may perform better on larger data types (as `long` stored in one register).

Answer (score 0):

The best gain of 64 bit platform is an amount of memory yours application can address. This means what you web application can support a larger amount of active sessions or/and longer sessions. Also you can store more data in the application cache. So keeping this in mind you can re architect you app.