# Targeting 64-bit

Tags: .net, web-applications, 64-bit

I'm building a web application on .Net and it will run on 64 bit server. Is there something special that I should do to take full advantage of 64 bits?

Only thing that comes to mind is that RAM is cheap and "unlimited" for 64bit, maybe I should cache as much as possible.

Edit: closing as duplicate of [What can I do to optimize my .NET Web sites and applications for 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291675/what-can-i-do-to-optimize-my-net-web-sites-and-applications-for-64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some good information [here](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2006/04/iis-aspnet-and-64-bit-performance.html).

After a quick read, it looks like the ability to address unlimited (essentially) memory makes applications behave better.  As long as the OS and the .NET CLR are the 64-bit versions, you automagically get the benefit.

I would caution that this is not a fix-all for poorly written apps, nor does it mean that you now have a bottomless pit in which to stuff cache items.  Keep your profiler handy and continue to write good code on a powerful platform.